# how to make bootstrap 4 table header sticky on top when page scroll

Tags: bootstrap-4, argon

I'm using argon dashboard by creative tim https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-dashboard/.
Now I want table header remains at the top when scrolling page. I tried using class sticky-top but it does not work.

```
                           <thead class="thead-light sticky-top">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col-2" class="sort" data-sort="name">Customer ID</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="budget">Company</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="status">Employees</th>
                                <th scope="col">Country</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="sort" data-sort="completion">Last admin login</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last employee login</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last invoice</th>
                                <th scope="col">Next invoice</th>
                                <th scope="col">Total invoiced</th>
                                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                <th scope="col">Created</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
```

What is the problem with the code? Anyone can do  this, comment below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `fixed-top` instead. It worked for me

Comment: But it floats at the top div not inside the card. Any idea? @Dave